# importxml formula google spreadhseets does not display required data

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get rate data with google spreasheets with IMPORTXML from this site.
https://garantex.io/trading/btcusd?lang=en

Like red line on screen.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfx6nzo2pgde0f5/Screen.png?dl=0

Whatever i tryied but nothing helps. No numbers

=IMPORTXML("https://garantex.io/trading/btcusd?lang=en"; "//table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0YUw.png)")
Show no numbers but only text like BTC.
How i can get table of number or first one number?

Answer (score 0):

The data on this Page (and this site generally) is created dynamically by javascript.

It is not possible to scrape or otherwise extract the data from the page using `IMPORTXML` or any of the other Google native functions.